# <function> referenced from; symbol(s) not found

Tags: c++, c, xcode, compiler-construction

I have a piece of C code that is used from a C++ function.  At the top of my C++ file I have the line: `#include "prediction.h"`

In `prediction.h` I have this:

```
#ifndef prediction  
#define prediction  

#include "structs.h"  

typedef struct {  
    double estimation;  
    double variance;  
} response;

response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions, double* observations,
                        int targets, location* targetPositions);

#endif
```

I also have `prediction.c`, which has:

```
#include "prediction.h"  

response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions, double* observations,
                        int targets, location* targetPositions) {  
    // code here  
}
```

Now, in my C++ file (which as I said includes prediction.h) I call that function, then compile (through Xcode) I get this error:

> > "runPrediction(int, location*, double*, int, location*)", referenced from:
> >     mainFrame::respondTo(char*, int)in mainFrame.o
> >     ld: symbol(s) not found
> >     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

prediction.c is marked for compilation for the current target.  I don't have any problems with other .cpp files not being compiled.  Any thoughts here?

Comment: Format code by prefixing it with 4 spaces, the 101010 button will do that for you. You can do inline code (the only way in comments) by surrounding the code with backticks, so \`some code\` becomes `some code`. I escaped the former backticks with a backslash.

Comment: Ah, I see, I think I tried to use both block quotes and the 4 spaces; no wonder it didn't work.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely the name of the function is being [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)*. You need to do the following:

```
extern "C" response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions,
                   double* observations, int targets, location* targetPositions);
```

Which tells it to treat it as a C function declaration.

<sub>*C++ mangles function names to give them unique names during the linking phase, for function overloading. C has no function overloading so does no such thing.</sub>

---

Just so you know, you can also make an `extern "C"` block, if you have multiple things to extern:

```
extern "C"
{
    response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions,
                   double* observations, int targets, location* targetPositions);

    // other stuff
}
```

And like [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065643/function-referenced-from-symbols-not-found/3065701#3065701) suggests, to allow the header to be used in both use `__cplusplus` to condition it:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define EXTERN_C extern "C"
#else
    #define EXTERN_C
#endif

EXTERN_C response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions,
                   double* observations, int targets, location* targetPositions);
```

Comment: For a mixed C/C++ project it's better to bracket `extern "C" {`/`}` with `#ifdef __cplusplus`/`#endif` so that the header can be #included by both C and C++ source files

Comment: @Paul: I forgot about that detail. :) If you don't mind, I'm going to add that.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is about.  I put `extern "C" response runPrediction...` and I get this error: `expected identifier or '(' before string constant`

Comment: @jfm429: Was that being compiled in C or C++? C has no `extern "C"`, hence the preprocessor define to toggle it.

Comment: Huh, the conditional extern works.  Is it possible that somehow it was being compiled once as C, and once as C++?  Anyway, I put the conditional ifdef in and it solved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @jfm429: yes, it gets compiled as C when you compile prediction.c (which #includes prediction.h) and again as C++ whenever you #include prediction.h in a C++ source file.

Answer (score 3):

Change prediction.h so that it looks like this:

```
#ifndef prediction  
#define prediction  

#include "structs.h"  

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {  
    double estimation;  
    double variance;  
} response;

response runPrediction(int obs, location* positions, double* observations,
                        int targets, location* targetPositions);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: It would be nice if I could accept multiple answers; this as well as the previous answer both helped.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Is 'prediciton' realy C and not C++?  You will have different default compilations based on the file extension, GMan covers this.

If it is ment to be C++ and you change the file name, I would still sugest that runPrediction should be marked extern in the header, it is not defined in the local C++ module defining class mainFrame.